# Python regex matching issue

Tags: python, regex, matching

I have a problem with regex and Python. I wrote a simple tool that will search text document to find lines I want to search for and then should make a new text file and copy extracted lines from the original one.

Here is the content of text document, one line below another:

1. C:\ProgramData\3ebdd88b-6153-1
2. C:\ProgramData\3ebdd88b-2d35-0
3. C:\ProgramData{2a0cdb44-612c-1}
4. C:\ProgramData{27e4a155-512c-0}

To match 3rd and 4th line I used this:

```
for line in lines:
        if re.search("ProgramData\\\{[\w\-]+\}", line) >= 0:
            fixes.append(line)
```

But I have a problem with 1st and 2nd line, no matter which pattern I used that was working on regex tester, it cannot find these lines later.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use raw string literals when using patterns tested online. In most cases, they will work without much modification.

Comment: may be you can try with **if re.search(r^"ProgramData\\\{[\w\-]+\}", line) >= 0:**

Comment: You are searching `C:\ProgramData{2a0cdb44-612c-1}` (without a \ after `ProgramData`) and in your Regex you are looking for a \ after `ProgramData`. So, `ProgramData{[\w\-]+\}` to match the 3rd and 4th line should work.

Comment: So, try just [`r'\\ProgramData(?:\{[\w-]+}|\\[\w-]+)'`](https://regex101.com/r/sR5eU6/2), and [this demo](https://ideone.com/q9IkNG)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following RegEx:

```
ProgramData(?:\{[\w-]+\}|\\[\w-]+)
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/wK0gS9/1)</kbd>

Your new code will be:

```
for line in lines:
    if re.search("ProgramData(?:\{[\w-]+\}|\\[\w-]+)", line) >= 0:
        fixes.append(line)
```

<kbd>[**Demo on Ideone**](https://ideone.com/pIvPM4)</kbd>

---

How the RegEx works:

```
ProgramData          # ProgramData
(?:                  # Non-Capturing Group for data after ProgramData
  \{[\w-]+\}           # {} enclosing a Letter or - (Hyphen) one or more times
  |                    # OR
  \\[\w-]+             # \ followed by a Letter or - (Hyphen) one or more times
)
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: That doesn't find anything. Regex isn't accurate at all or Python is using some totally different Regex, and when you test it live, it doesn't do anything. Thank you all for your comments, but it seems this can't be solved. I'll try something on my own.